# What is an elegant way to find min value in a subset of an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array `a` of 100 integers. What is a recommended way to find the min value in `a[3]` through `a[70]` **AND the index of this min value**? Assuming no duplication of values.

I know the clumsy way of looping through the relevant range of indices:

```
for(i = 3; i < 70, i++) 
{
    ...
}
```

I am looking for a more elegant way of doing this in C# instead of looping. Thanks.

Comment: If only `ArraySegment<T>` was enumerable...

Comment: @Mehrdad How is the difference if it is enumerable? Thanks.

Comment: Well then you could just say `foreach (var item in new ArraySegment<int>(arr, 3, 70))`... it'd get rid of the `i`.

Comment: But he wants the index of that item anyway.  There's really no better option than the naïve way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To Find out min

```
List<int> templist = a.Skip(3).Take(67).ToList();

int minimum = templist.Min();
```

For Index

```
int index = templist.FindIndex(i => i == minimum) + 3;
```

I added 3 because index in list will be 3 less than index in original sequence `a`.

What it is doing

1. Skip - Leaves first 3 values i.e. index 0,1,2 and returns remaining array.
2. Take - From the array returned by Skip it takes 67 values. (Since your for loop goes till starts from 3 and goes till 70 so you are basically looping on 67 items bcoz 70 - 3 = 67).
3. ToList - Converts returned sequence to List for finding index.
4. Min - Gets minimum from of it.

You have to use loop since it is a sequence. Since you said elegant so instead of for loop I used LINQ (Even it does that looping also).

Comment: How do you know which index of this min value? The statement just give me the min, I think. Thanks.

Comment: @RJIGO: Do you want all indexes of this value or the first index?

Comment: Just the first index because there is no duplication of values.

Comment: @MarkSowul: Because for index i do not have to again do skip and take. Updated Answer

Comment: Your index is off by the number of items skipped

Answer (score 3):

If your data structure is not sorted then there is no way to do it without looping through all the elements in the sublist, either if you use some implicit looping through the provided API.

You cannot use a sorted collection since you are working on a subpart of it (so you'd need to create a sorted collection for the part of the list just for it), so in any case you'll have to loop over it.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ's `Aggregate` is not the easiest, but it is arguably the least inefficient of the "elegant" solutions (though they're still more lines of code than the straightforward loop.  Additionally, iterating through yourself is still the best because you are not allocating any additional memory).

But anyway, should you feel the need to make your successor hang you in effigy, you can do this instead of a straightforward loop:

`var minValueAndItsIndex = a

.Skip(3)

.Take(70 - 3)

.Select((value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index + 3})

.Aggregate((tuple1, tuple2) => (tuple1.Value < tuple2.Value) ? tuple1 : tuple2);`

If you create a 2-item `ValueType`-based tuple and use that instead of the anonymous type, it will be comparable to the more-efficient direct iteration because it won't allocate any additional memory.